# Appender with multi-class example for logging system

Tags: c++, logging, append, log4cplus

I'm newbie working with a logging system, but it's something very useful to add to your programs.

Summarizing my problem. I use the logging library **log4cplus**

I doing and easy example with two simple classes and the main program.

That's my error log:

- log4cplus:ERROR No appenders could be found for logger (main).
- log4cplus:ERROR Please initialize the log4cplus system properly.
- Segmentation fault: 11

The problem is i don't know how to solve the problem with the appender.

That's basic code of my example.
**Class1.h**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <log4cplus/configurator.h>
#include <log4cplus/logger.h>

using namespace std;
// Use the log4cplus namespace
using namespace log4cplus;

class one
{
    private:
        // Create the logger
        Logger logger;

    public:
        bool flag;
        int valor;

        one();  
        int multiplica(int a);  
};
```

**Class1.cpp**

```
one::one()
{
    logger.getInstance(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("Clase One - constructor.")); 
}

int one::multiplica(int a)
{
    int sol = 0;

    sol = valor * a;

    // Imprimo un mesaje en el log.
    LOG4CPLUS_INFO(logger, "El resultado de la multiplicación es: xx");

    return sol;
}
```

**Class2.h**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <log4cplus/configurator.h>
#include <log4cplus/logger.h>

using namespace std;
// Use the log4cplus namespace
using namespace log4cplus;

class two
{
    private:
        // Create the logger
        Logger logger;

    public:
        bool flag;
        int valor;

        two();
        int suma(int a);    
};
```

**Class.cpp**

```
two::two()
{
    logger.getInstance(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("Clase Two - DEconstructor.")); 
}

int two::suma(int a)
{
    int sol = 0;

    sol = valor + a;

    // Imprimo un mesaje en el log.
    LOG4CPLUS_INFO(logger, "El resultado de la suma es: YY ");

    return sol;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Load the properties
    PropertyConfigurator::doConfigure("logClase.properties");
    Logger logger = Logger::getInstance(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("main"));

    // Log with INFO level
    if (logger.isEnabledFor(INFO_LOG_LEVEL))
    {
        LOG4CPLUS_INFO(logger, "Application startup");
    }

        one uno;
        two dos;

        uno.valor = dos.valor = 4;
        uno.multiplica(7);
        dos.suma(7);

    // Log with INFO level
    if (logger.isEnabledFor(INFO_LOG_LEVEL))
    {
        LOG4CPLUS_INFO(logger, "Application shutdown");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What i'm doing wrong ??? 
That's the correct way to work with the logging system ??

I use a simple properties file to save all the log messages in a file.

That's my **logClase.properties** file to configure de logger.

```
log4cplus.rootLogger=INFO, STDOUT, FILEAPPENDER
log4cplus.logger.main=INFO
log4cplus.logger.utils=FILEAPPENDER

log4cplus.appender.STDOUT=log4cplus::ConsoleAppender
log4cplus.appender.STDOUT.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout
log4cplus.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S} [%t] %-5p %c{2} %%%x%% - %m [%l]%n

log4cplus.appender.FILEAPPENDER=log4cplus::RollingFileAppender
log4cplus.appender.FILEAPPENDER.File=KlasseEx.log
log4cplus.appender.FILEAPPENDER.MaxFileSize=5MB
#log4cplus.appender.FILEAPPENDER.MaxFileSize=500KB
log4cplus.appender.FILEAPPENDER.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4cplus.appender.FILEAPPENDER.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout
log4cplus.appender.FILEAPPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S} [%t] %-5p %c{2} %%%x%% - %m [%l]%n
```

I want to use FILEAPPENDER and the Console appender to throw messages in a file and into the console. I think that's not must be so difficult to do, it must be easy to do it.

Comment: What version of log4cplus and build system and compiler are you using? Is it MinGW? Are you using log4cplus as DLL? I have recently fixed one problem in MinGW/DLL code that could be causing it.

Comment: OSX 10.8 and latest version of log4cplus. I compile my code with a makefile without errors.

Comment: That is one platform that I have no way of testing. Please try to obtain a stack trace using a debugger. Also, just for sure, state the log4cplus version number, please.

Answer (score 2):

See for appenders in log4cplus documentation. You probably missing some step of intialitation of this logger - I mean you did not add appenders.

See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15955/logging-made-easy-in-your-c-applications

After:

```
Logger logger = Logger::getInstance(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("main"));
```

Missing:

```
SharedAppenderPtr consoleAppender(new ConsoleAppender());
consoleAppender->setName("myAppenderName");
consoleAppender->setLayout(new log4cplus::TTCCLayout());
logger.addAppender(consoleAppender);
```

Comment: He calls `PropertyConfigurator::doConfigure("logClase.properties");` so it should be initialized, unless something's wrong in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

PiotrNycz mentioned that you indeed needed to do more initialization steps for your log4cplus logging, particularly adding appenders. I want to elaborate more on that.

[Documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/log4cplus/wiki/CodeExamples/#initialization) states that prior to version 2.0 initialization is to be done with:

`log4cplus::initialize();`

and deinitialization, by calling `shutdown()` on the `Logger` like so:

`log4cplus::Logger::getRoot().shutdown();`

, while after version 2.0, initialization is supposed to occur with instantiating the RAII class `log4cplus::Initializer initializer;` and deinitialization when that instance is destructed.

**However** I have version 2.0.0 and the prior method is what actually has worked for me. With the 2nd method I was getting the exact same error you did.

Then a minimal implementation of logging for a class could be like so:

```
const wchar_t* PATTERN = LOG_PATTERN; // optional - create an initial log status message
log4cplus::SharedAppenderPtr consoleApp(new log4cplus::ConsoleAppender());  // for console output
consoleApp->setLayout(std::unique_ptr<log4cplus::Layout>(new log4cplus::PatternLayout(PATTERN))); // again optional
log4cplus::Logger m_logger = log4cplus::Logger::getRoot();  // get root logger
m_logger.setLogLevel(log4cplus::ALL_LOG_LEVEL);     // set root logger log level

// finally add appenders
this->m_logger.addAppender(consoleApp); // at least one appender must be set in order for you to be able to actually log to the console or file or to an output device (multiple appender types exist).
```

Now, a custom `MyLogger` class should minimally contain a `log4cplus::Logger`, logging functions - like the following `logError` - and the initialization steps mentioned above done in its constructor. Also, it needs a member function `GetLogger` defined as such: `log4cplus::Logger* GetLogger(const char* logger = DEFAULT_LOGGER);` to acquire a MyLogger instance and use it as a member of a class for which you want to provide the logging facilities.

To log a specific message you also need a function like this in `MyLogger`:

```
template<typename... Args>
inline void logError(const char* stringOptionallyFormatted, Args&&... args)
{
    LOG4CPLUS_ERROR_FMT(m_logger, fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

(Likewise for other log levels.)

Now instantiate a logger instance in some class's constructor (or in `main`):

```
MyLogger myLoggerInstance;
myLoggerInstance.GetLogger(L"File System Logger");
```

and log with:

`myLoggerInstance.logError|Info|Debug("like today is %s No%d", "Sunday", 7 );`

or:

`logger.logDebug(L"no formatted string");`

---

Additional notes:

- I have found documenetation for log4cplus to be relatively poor. [This](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) (which is for log4j! - the java original) tutorial is the best one I have found. It explains the basics very well. Then the page I linked above as well.
- Make sure you call `log4cplus::initialize()` first thing in main to prevent SIOF.
- Typically you want one `Logger` member object per class you're interested in.
- If you're working on a multithreaded application call `log4cplus::threadCleanup();` as an additional de-initialization step *after* calling `shutdown`.
- Only a trivial hello world app [link](https://sourceforge.net/p/log4cplus/wiki/CodeExamples/#hello-world) wouldn't need an appender.